# AWS S3 link expired after a few minutes

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I uploaded a picture to my S3 bucket to use as a background image for my website.

I retrieve the URL by selecting the imagine **Action<Open** then just copy the URL and put it in my image tag **src**. For like 5 minutes the image shows up on the website but then after a while the image doesn't show and I go to the link and it gives me **request has expired** error.

There's probably a simple solution to this but I cant figure it out.

Comment: Hi. I've noticed that you have lots of questions with answers, yet not a single answer was ever accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good practice, but it also reduced duplicates and makes your questions more likely to be answered.

Comment: @Marcin didn't think of that, I'll get on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because S3 console creates [S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) with default expiration of 300 seconds.

If you want to make the links to your images permanent and accessible from your website you have to make them public as explained in:

- [How can I grant public read access to some objects in my Amazon S3 bucket?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/)

Other possibility without making objects public is to use CloudFront as explained in:

- [Amazon S3 + Amazon CloudFront: A Match Made in the Cloud](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/)